# Possible in one formula in google sheets?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, nested-if, ifs

I'm new to formulas in google sheets but doing ok with online learning.
I have come across something I need to do that I cant find a solution for.

I have this that works:

```
=if(O13>=Q14,O13-INFO!L5*O13,0)
```

But now I need to also include a cap to the returned value so if it reaches a certain number it will stop and return no more than a value found in another cell (in this case it would be "INFO!M5").

Is this possible within the same formula and if this type of thing has a certain name for phrase I don't know, is that why I cant find help on it.

Thanks
Adam

Comment: can you share a spreadsheet with expected output?

Comment: Thanks, like my answer to player0 I need to go and have a look at my original formula, but i'll share if I get stuck with that, thanks for replying!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `nested-if`:

```
=IF(O13>=Q14, IF((O13-INFO!L5*O13)<=INFO!M5, O13-INFO!L5*O13, INFO!M5), 0)
```

### update:

```
=IF((G7>=0)*(G7<=I7), G7-G7*K7, M7 )
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Thanks,
The capping worked but its made me realise the formula I had written wasn't doing exactly what I thought it was up to that value so I need to go back and  look at it. 
Thanks for your help so far though!

Comment: I looked at nesting but couldn't get my head round it, but I wasn't using spaces inside, does that make a difference?

Comment: @Adam if you could share a copy/sample of your sheet with example of desired result I'm happy to help

Comment: thanks, I just need to relook at what I'm trying to do, I think I've approached it in the wrong way. So will come back with the sheet when I have got my head around what it is I'm wanting. thanks

Comment: Hi I have a link to the sheet here with what I have got so far:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QiKAmQXsmeZAOtl2jyMKhrA1Isz1dq1w4jQC-r6-yIU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Adam answer & your sheet updated

Comment: Hi thanks, the result is showing what the 97% of the value is rather than the result. IE if the sum total is 2100 the value should show 63 after the 97% has been removed, does that make sense?